# Convertir variable javascript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jspdf

Mi problema consiste en que tengo un boton el cual envía un parametro a una funcion javascript.
Al recibirlo en esta función, quiero ejecutar una consulta sql donde el where incluya esta variable recibida (esto para generar un pdf jspdf y no tener que visualizar todos los campos para descargar).
Mi consulta es si es posible recibir esta variable en el PHP, ya que cuando imprimo la alerta me muestra un campo vació.

```
<?php 
 function prueba(dse) { //debería ir sobre el php
  $a=dse;

$q=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tabla WHERE id='$a'");

  $ro=mysql_fetch_array($q);   
alert(<php? echo $ro['id'];?>);//deberia ir bajo del PHP              
 ?>
```

Agradecido de respuestas y cualquier alternativa es valida

Comment: Tu variable debe ir por POST a un controlador PHP donde la recivas $variable = $_POST['variable']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo algunos conceptos. La función que publicaste junto con tu pregunta es código PHP, por lo que entiendo lo que estás tratando de hacer es enviar desde Javascript un valor a un archivo PHP para procesarlo en el servidor.

Esto puedes hacerlo mediante consultas POST al servidor con [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

Ejemplos:

**Javascript**:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //Respuesta a la consulta
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "tuArchivo.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
  urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("variable=valor&..."); //(en tu caso, el valor 'dse')
```

en donde en el método `xhttp.send("variable=valor&...")` envías los datos al servidor.

**JQuery**:

-$.post(URL,data,callback);

```
        $.post("tuArchivo.php",
        {
          variable:valor, //(en tu caso, el valor 'dse')
          ...
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

Estas secciones puedes ponerlas en el evento `click` asociado a tu botón para enviar la consulta con los parámetros.

Luego, en el archivo tuArchivo.php lo recibes de esta forma:

```
$valor = $_POST["nombre"];
```

en este punto ya podés trabajar en el servidor con la variable $valor para hacer referencia al dato enviado desde Javascript.

Esto es sólo un ejemplo sencillo, te recomiendo esta [lectura](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) para comenzar.

Answer (score 0):

primeramente debes ir actualizando tu version de php ya que **mysql** esta obsoleta es insegura  por lo tanto mudate a mysqli o PDO [este es un buen articulo en donde aprenderas aserca de ello](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

luego bien para hacer lo que quieres hay varias maneras ya sea solo **php** o **php** con **ajax** es lo mas recomendable y mas dinamico para la experiencia de usuario e aqui un ejemplo

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

         $("#formulario").submit(function(e){//aqui obtendrias la accion del el formulario al enviarse  y asignadole el parametro e para evitar que se refresque la pagina 

            var id=$("#idVariable");//aqui recivirias el valor del input o campo que deceas para luego mandarlo a un archivo php para hacer el filtro

 e.preventDefault();//evitamos que se refresque la pagina para obtener un resultado mas dinamico
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',//mandamos los datos atrves de post ya que es mas seguro 
                    url: 'tu_archivo_para_recivir_varivble_id.php',
                    data:{id:id},//enviamos el la variable id
                    success: function(data)//el success te dira si a tenido exito tu consulta
                    {
                        //Manejar la respuesta del otro php como quieras ejemplo 
                    }
                });
            })
        });
```

y el php a donde recive los datos quedaria asi por ejemplo:

```
    <?php

    $id = $_POST['idVariable'];//aqui recivimos la variable id

       $sql= mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT id FROM tabla WHERE id='$id' ");//estoy suponiendo que la varible de tu conexion a la base de datos se llama $mysqli

      if($sql){//si la consulta sql tiene esxito ejecuta el siguiente codigo

      $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);//en la variable row se guardaran los datos de la consulta   

  //ejemplo puedes sacar los nombres de los campos que tienes en tu tabla e inprimirlos asi 
   echo $row["campo1"]; //esto seria el callback que se reciviaria en el success de tu archivo js

}
?>
```

espero que sea de tu ayuda saludos!